# heroku Cannot find module '@nestjs/mapped-types'

Tags: heroku, nestjs

i am working on a nest application, everything is working perfectly on my local server but once i send it to heroku and try to access the application it throws errors. on further exploration, i ran `heroku logs --tail` and i saw these errors:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251416+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251416+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251417+00:00 app[web.1]:
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251420+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '@nestjs/mapped-types'
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251420+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251421+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/dist/DTO/UserDto.js
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251421+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/dist/user/user.controller.js
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251421+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/dist/user/user.module.js
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251421+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/dist/app.module.js
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251422+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/dist/main.js
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251429+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251429+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251430+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251430+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251430+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/DTO/UserDto.js:14:24)
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251430+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251431+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251431+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251431+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251431+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251431+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251432+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251432+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/dist/DTO/UserDto.js',
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251432+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/dist/user/user.controller.js',
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251432+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/dist/user/user.module.js',
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251432+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/dist/app.module.js',
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251433+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/dist/main.js'
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251433+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2024-03-04T14:25:17.251433+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

the path `'/app/dist/DTO/UserDto.js'` does not exist in my app, what exists is `'/dist/DTO/UserDto.js'`, i am guessing that, that is the problem, but i don't know how to fix it.

by the way here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "<NAME_OF_PROJECT>",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.2.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.2",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.9.2",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.20",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^2.0.5",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.38",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: what if you drop the `@nestjs/mapped-types` from dev dependencies list?